# Azure MSI using app services

Tags: azure, web-applications

I am trying to protect my backing services to my frontend webapp using MSI and AAD auth.

I keep getting a 401 when I call my backing services form the public facing webapp. I have added the public webapp as a reader in the IAM section of the backing services.

What I can't figure out is how to obtain the access token, it seems that no matter which endpoint I use for obtaining the access token, it says that it is not found.

Here is my code:

```
{
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string accessToken = azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://<mywebapi>.azurewebsites.net").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

RemoteIp = httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://<mywebapi>.azurewebsites.net/api/default/remoteIp").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
LocalIp =  httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://<mywebapi>.azurewebsites.net/api/default/localIp").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
ConnectionId = httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://<mywebapi>.azurewebsites.net/api/default/connectionId").GetAwaiter().GetResult();            
}
```

And here is the error message:

```
Parameters: Connectionstring: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://<mywebapi>.azurewebsites.net, Authority: . 
Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. 
Unable to connect to the Managed Service Identity (MSI) endpoint. 
Please check that you are running on an Azure resource that has MSI setup.
```

**UPDATE:**
<mywebapi>  is obviously the actual endpoint value, but not exposed here on stackoverflow. Furthermore I should mention that calling the API endpoints directly works fine, after I have authorized with my personal credentials xxx@xxx.xxx. The issue is related to the webapp trying to identify itself to the webapi, even though it is a registered application which has been assigned the necessary IAM rights on the webapi resource.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it tried to use MSI, but could not. Are you sure you are running this code on the Web App with MSI enabled?

Also, you need to replace `"https://<mywebapi>.azurewebsites.net"` with the App Id URI or Application Id of your API in Azure AD.
*In other words, this needs to match the valid audience that you have configured for the API*.